# Where can i find the responsive css in Stencil on Bigcommerce?

Tags: css, bigcommerce, responsive

I'm trying to edit the css for the header, but i can't find where the responsive css is coming from. I've looked in most of the scss folder but couldn't find it.

I'm on Bigcommerce using the Cornerstone theme on Stencil.

Let me know if I left any other info out.

Thank you.

Comment: Big Commerce themes generally tend to have a seperate responsive.css file. Have you looked for that. I have added this as a comment because it is not a hard and fast rule and I have seen templates that just add @media css in a terribly ad hoc fashion all over the place. (I am not familiar with that particular theme).

Comment: Hey PaulD, ya that's how it is in the Blueprint framework but not the stencil framework. the new framework uses .scss files instead of .css

Comment: Have you checked in /assets/scss/layouts/header/_header.scss?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for assisting me Alyss, although your response was pretty vague.

The Stencil framework uses `@include breakpoint(...)` instead of `@media screen...`

To change the dimensions for the responsive sizes, you will need to edit 2 files. From the initial `stencil` folder, navigate to `/assets/js/theme/common/media-query-list.js` for the first file and `/assets/scss/settings/global/screensizes/_screensizes.scss` for the second file.

This is the snippet for the js file. Simply edit the values for `large, medium, and small`:

```
const breakpointSizes = {
    large: 1261,
    medium: 801,
    small: 551,
};
```

This is the snippet for the scss file. Edit the values for `$screen-large, $screen-medium, and $screen-small` with the same values you used for the js file:

```
$screen-large:                  1261px;
$screen-medium:                 801px;
$screen-small:                  551px;
```

Below is a snippet of the header.scss file. The '@include breakpoint("medium")' is the responsive styling for medium sized windows, which we know is 801 from the previous two files.

```
.header {
    background-color: $header-bg;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: zIndex("low");

    @include breakpoint("medium") {
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
    }

    &.is-open {
        height: 100%;

        @include breakpoint("medium") {
            height: auto;
        }
    }
    &:after {
        clear: both;
        content: '';
        display: block;
    }
}
```